# conditional join tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have two tables. I want list of all activity that is allowed and not allowed to guest_id 1 from these tables.

first table

```
activity_name_id | activity_name |

    1                 Entry

    2                 Exit

    3                 Break
```

second table

```
allowed_guest_id | allowed_activity_name_id |
    1                 1
    2                 1
    1                 3
    2                 4
```

Now I want the result

```
activity_name_id | activity_name |allowed_guest_id | allowed_activity_name_id |

    1                 Entry                1                 1

    2                 Exit                 null              2

    3                 Break                1                 3
```

I have already tried. But It returns two rows only. first and last.

```
select * from table_activity_name
    left join table_allowed_activity 
    on activity_name_id = allowed_activity_name_id
        where allowed_activity_guest_id = 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put your `allowed_activity_guest_id = 1` condition in `ON clause` instead of `where`

```
select * from table_activity_name
    left join table_allowed_activity 
    on activity_name_id = allowed_activity_name_id
        and allowed_activity_guest_id = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
select ta.activity_name_id, ta.activity_name, tal.allowed_guest_id, tal.allowed_activity_name_id from table_activity_name as ta
left join table_allowed_activity  as tal
on ta.activity_name_id = tal.allowed_activity_name_id
and tal.allowed_activity_guest_id = 1;
```

or IN operation

```
select ta.activity_name_id, ta.activity_name, tal.allowed_guest_id, tal.allowed_activity_name_id from table_activity_name as ta
left join table_allowed_activity  as tal
on ta.activity_name_id = tal.allowed_activity_name_id
and tal.allowed_activity_guest_id in (1,2);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a condition applied  to a left join table column you must set this condition in ON clause of the related  left joined  table

```
select * 
from table_activity_name
left join table_allowed_activity 
    on activity_name_id = allowed_activity_name_id 
        AND  allowed__guest_id = 1;
```

If you use where for these condition the query work as an inner join